# How to change [] with {} in my array object

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I retrieve this data from an API

```
{"city":"New York","type":["0","1","9"]}
```

I need to convert in this way:

```
{"type":{0:true,1:true,9:true},...}
```

I try with angular foreach in this way

```
var tmparr = [];
angular.forEach( $scope.path.type, function (value, key)  {
    tmparr.push(value + ":true")
});
$scope.checkfilters.type = tmparr
```

but in this way i have this result and it's not what i need

```
{"business_type":["0:true","1:true","9:true"]}
```

I don't know how to replace the [] with {} in my array

If I try to set ***var tmparr = {}*** I have undefined error in push function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bracket syntax

```
var tmparr = {};
angular.forEach( $scope.path.type, function (value, key)  {
    tmparr[value] = true;
});
$scope.checkfilters.type = tmparr;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the type and then copy the values and assign it to true.

```js
var original = {"city":"New York","type":["0","1","9"]};
var copy = {};
for(var i in original.type){
   copy[original.type[i]] = true;
}

console.log(copy);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `reduce` with an object accumulator:

```js
var data = {"city":"New York","type":["0","1","9"]}

const result = data.type.reduce((r,c) => (r[c] = true, r), {})

console.log(result)
```